# Porque no me esta funcionando este FULL OUTER JOIN - Consultas SQL

Tags: datatables, sql

Quiero sacar los datos de todos los empleados que estén en una u otra tabla, no en ambas

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(a.Nombre, b.Nombre) AS Personas /*Saca el primer registro no nulo de ambas columnas*/
FROM (SELECT Nombre
  FROM tab1) a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Nombre
  FROM tab2) b 
 ON a.Nombre = b.Nombre WHERE (a.Nombre IS NULL) OR (b.Nombre IS NULL)
```

Comment: Coloca la estructura de tus tablas, de ser posible un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de los datos de salida que esperas obtener

Comment: Si el tema es que me da error de Sintaxis

Comment: Comparte el RDBMS que estás usando. En SQL Server no da error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer SELECT querés obtener los registros no nulos

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(a.Nombre, b.Nombre)
```

pero la condición es que los registros sean nulos

```
WHERE (a.Nombre IS NULL) OR (b.Nombre IS NULL)
```

¿¿ ??